# ¿Como puedo ingresar un dato en una tabla en pgAdmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

He descargado la versión 4 de pgAdmin, pero al momento de tratar ingresar un dato, no encuentro la manera de hacerlo gráficamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He encontrado la solución, para poder agregar una nueva columna en una tabla en pgAdmin4 la tabla debe contar con una llave primaria (primary key), de lo contrario la opción para agregar datos se deshabilita.